# USBLC6-2P6 - does the direction matter?

Tags: usb, stm32, esd, usb-c, st

I'm designing a simple PCB with STM32F4 MCU and USB, and I want to use USBLC6-2P6 for ESD protection. However, using the EDS protection device as presented in the datasheet creates the need for me to cross DP and DM lines twice (once on connector-USBLC6 traces, and once on USBLC6-MCU traces).

[image]

USBC labels are for the connector, USB labels are for the MCU.
Can I reverse the connections to the ESD protection device, and connect the USB connector on pins 6 and 4, while connecting the MCU on pins 1 and 3?

Comment: "Can I reverse the connections..." Yes.  But don't swap 2 & 5, or you'll have a bad day.

Comment: You can also measure the device with a DMM, and you will find shorts between 1 and 6, and a short between 3 and 4.

Comment: You can swap USB_DP with USBC_DP without any problem, it is just a direct wire internally. What I usually do is to have 4 - 6 connecting to the USB connector, as it provide the shortest paths and closer to the connector, pin 2 is always go through the via to the GND plate. 1 and 3 go to the whatever chip you are connecting to as differential pair.

Answer (score 1):

The IO1 and IO2 channels are identical.

You can swap DP and DN to go through IO1 and IO2 in any way you like.